# Is there a way to know the type of output inside a template file?

Tags: theming

I am making a website for both WAP and smartphone browser, and I am using two themes to display WML and HTML. Now I have a problem to show a `<anchor>` link. The pseudo-code for the code I would use in the template file is the following one:

```
if (HTML_THEME) {
  print '<a href = "history.go(-1)">BACK</a>';
} 
else{
  print '<anchor>BACK<prev/></anchor>';
}
```

Could anybody tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`$theme_key`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/theme_key/7) global, which gives you the:

> Name of the active theme.

You can use it like so:

```
global $theme_key;
if ($theme_key == 'mobile_theme') {
  // ...
}
else {
  // ...
}
```